# Black screen with flashing blinking cursor

Tags: boot, 13.10

As you could guess, I have some problems with my computer, I'm trying to boot to Linux (I tried with Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Manjaro) but I'm keep getting a black screen with a blinking cursor like this:

[image: black screen with a blinking cursor]

I already tried to search for solutions on the web but I cannot find any solutions, (I tried [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/6695#6695?newreg=89539fdcfc284eac9476d82d9cf4a6bb)) but nothing is working.

I have:

- Evga GTX 780 SC video card
- Gigabyte Z87X UD5H
- Intel i7 4770k

So if you have any ideas or solutions that would be great.

Comment: Please describe more verbose: what commands did you try and what output was.

Comment: I cannot get any commands, I cannot get a terminal, without any boot option I get the flashing cursor on Ubuntu, and with manjaro the boot freeze at "triggering uevents" (I can overpass this with the safe settings but then I get the blinking screen). With Ubuntu when nomodeset boot option, I just get a totally black screen.

Comment: Is it installed or live system? Is it OK on live system?

Comment: I'm trying to install it on a SSD.

Comment: Did you try alternate installer?

Comment: What do you mean by alternate installer?

Comment: Text-based installer like [this (torrent)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)

Comment: I'm going to test it, the download will be done in less than 10 minutes, thanks :)

Comment: It looks to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and use [Alternate Installer CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent). It has text-based installer which should work on your system. After the installation, `chroot` to installed system and update it. You might also need [Xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) to be installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```