# Blinking cursor and very clean and black screen on Linux

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a screen like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444783/black-screen-with-flashing-blinking-cursor), I guess it is caused by running out of disk space.

I tried so many solutions and none is worked, tried to boot to windows 10 and get access to Linux files and delete them and did not work, also I tried to use rescue kali and did not work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Before running around trying "*so many solutions*," consider troubleshooting the problem. For example, if you *guess* that your disk space is full, why not use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" and verify that's really the problem? A useful solution depends upon knowing the problem.

Comment: Also, trying to fix a broken Linux installation from Windows is a recipe for desaster. Your Linux installation might have been fixable before that, but very probably isn't anymore now that you went around deleting files in it from Windows. Reinstalling from scratch is probably the best approach now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a live USB stick with Ubuntu. Start it, mount your linux drive (by clicking on it in the Ubuntu filemanager) and remove your files.

Since Windows does not know much about Linux file systems, this is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I used [DiskGenius](https://www.eassos.com/partitionguru.php) to delete files and free up at least 6GB and It worked!

Thank you all for your answers! I literally spent all the day on it.